# How to use git diff with --no-merges option?

Tags: git, merge

I would like to use `git diff` with `--after=date` or `commit_id` but only for commits done on checkout branch including merge commits from feature branches, not release_current?

There is no result using: `git log --graph --oneline --after=2016-02-11 --no-merges release_current`.

There is result using: `git diff --name-only 6c475ecd122e5a2569931ee9425517453a935bb5` but I can't filtered out merges from release_current branch.

Just info:

There is also nice command: `git diff --diff-filter=ACMRT --name-only 176bb1eb4c108c86f938646cc325fa5ec6afcc5d > test1.txt`
but there is a bug. Deleted file and created same one in two different commits, will not create line in result set.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want to achieve. Maybe you can supply some example of commits, branches?

Comment: It looks like each of the commands you've tried include `--name-only`.  If that's the case, why not just use `git log`'s `--name-only` argument? It will be the same output. That way you can combine it with `--no-merges`.

Comment: I would like to have list of changed files like git diff command creates, but with possibilities to removes commits came as merge from release_current branch.